# Mixed-radix maximal digits $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{(2i)i!}{(2i+1)!!} = 2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, factorial

In [A Spigot Algorithm for the Digits of π by Rabinowitz and Wagon](https://maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/pubs/amm_supplements/Monthly_Reference_12.pdf), the following lemma says the "maximal digit" representation $(0;2,4,6,8\dots)$ in the mixed-radix base $(\frac 1 3, \frac 2 5, \frac 3 7, \dots)$ is bounded by 2:

$$0 + \frac 1 3 \left(2 + \frac 2 5 \left( 4 + \frac 3 7 ( 6 + \cdots ) \right) \right) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{(2i)i!}{(2i+1)!!} = 2$$

They sketch a proof by induction based on remainders: the differences of the partial sum and 2. Is there a direct proof based on combinatorial interpretation or well-known series? The $\pi/2$ formula of $(1;1,1,1,1,\dots)$ is apparently due to Newton and can be derived from the arctan Taylor series.

Comment: https://www.mdpi.com/2227-7390/5/3/40 p28 remark 4 related problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have a telescopic series
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n \cdot n!}{(2n+1)!!}
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2n+1)n!-(n+1)n!}{(2n+1)!!} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \Big(\frac{n!}{(2n-1)!!} - \frac{(n+1)!}{(2n+1)!!}\Big)\\
&= \frac{0!}{(-1)!!} - \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{(n+1)!}{(2n+1)!}\\
&= 1.
\end{align*}
We have set $(-1)!! = 1$ to keep the relation $(2n+1)!! = (2n+1)(2n-1)!!$ true when $n=0$.

Comment: Very nice. Seems obvious now!

Answer (score 4):

It will be fascinating to have a combinatorial/probabilistic interpretation of the sum.

Unfortunately, I don't have a good lead in this direction yet. Let me think about this, but in the meantime, here is an analytic solution:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n \cdot n!}{(2n+1)!!}
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{n}n \frac{(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{n}n \int_{0}^{1} x^n(1-x)^n \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{2x(1-x)}{(1 - 2x(1-x))^2} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \left[ \frac{2x - 1}{2(1 - 2x(1-x))} \right]_{0}^{1}
= 1.
\end{align*}

Now the desired conclusion follows by multiplying both sides by $2$.

Comment: Thank you, I will  try to understand your solution. Does the integral come from the Beta distribution? I'm trying to work out the third step as well.

Comment: @qwr, Indeed, I utilized the beta function integral $$\int_{0}^{1}x^a (1-x)^b\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{a!b!}{(a+b+1)!},$$ where $\operatorname{Re}(a)>-1$ and $\operatorname{Re}(b)>-1$. When $a$ and $b$ are non-negative integers, this is quite easy to prove by comparing both sides of $$ \frac{z^{n+1}-1}{z-1}=\int_{0}^{1}(n+1)(1-x+zx)^n\,\mathrm{d}x=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(n+1)\binom{n}{k}\left(\int_{0}^{1}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)z^k. $$

Answer (score 3):

Here's a probabilistic interpretation of the equivalent identity
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n\cdot n!}{(2n+1)!!},$$
inspired by Christophe Leuridan's telescoping-based answer.

Begin at time $t=0$. At time $t$, pick a uniformly random element of $\{0,1,\ldots,2t\}$. It the element is greater than $t$, terminate; otherwise, continue. It is easy to see that this process terminates with probability $1$. On the other hand, the probability that it terminates exactly at time $t=n$ is
$$\left(\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\Pr\big[\text{does not terminate at $t=k$}\big]\right)\cdot\Pr\big[\text{terminates at $t=n$}\big],$$
which is
$$\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1-\frac k{2k+1}\right)\cdot\frac n{2n+1}=\frac{n\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(k+1)}{(2n+1)\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(2k+1)}=\frac{n\cdot n!}{(2n+1)!!}.$$
We conclude that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n\cdot n!}{(2n+1)!!}=\Pr[\text{process terminates}]=1.$$

Comment: (+1) Nice observation! Now suddenly the equality looks almost trivial...

Answer (score 0):

Another way.

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{2i\,i!}{(2i+1)!!}=
\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{2^{i+1}i(i!)^2}{(2i+1)!}=
\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{i\,i!}{2^{i-1}(\tfrac32)_{(i)}}\\=
2\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{\left[(i+1)!-i!\right]i!}{(\tfrac32)_{(i)}}\tfrac{(\tfrac12)^i}{i!}\\\stackrel{EIF}{=}
2\left(_2F_1(2,1;\tfrac32;\tfrac12)-
_2F_1(2,1;\tfrac32;\tfrac12)
\right)\\
=\tfrac2{B(1,\tfrac12)}\left(\int_0^1(1-x)^{-1/2}(1-\tfrac12x)^{-2}dx-
\int_0^1(1-x)^{-1/2}(1-\tfrac12x)^{-1}dx\right)\\
=\int_0^1\frac{2xdx}{\sqrt{1-x}(2-x)^2}=2.
$$
Evaluation of integral is by WolframAlpha.

$EIF:$ Euler Integral Formula for $_2F_1$ [hypergeometric function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is beyond my math knowledge.

Comment: I dont have enough experience in these topics too. I took EIF from wikipedia.